# How can I tell if my XML has been correctly parsed to JSON?

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I've been working on a project lately and decided to take a **crack at JSON instead of using XSLT stylesheets**.

I am trying to use the ***Fyneworks XML --> JSON plugin in convert my XML file loaded via Ajax***.

How can I tell if this has been converted correctly so I can start parsing it.

Here is the HTML and Ajax call with jquery which i have tried so far.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.xml2json.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
             $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             url:"lou.xml",
             datatype:"xml",
             success: function(xml) {
            $.get('lou.xml',function(xml) {
                   var json=$.xml2json(xml);
                   alert(json.message); 
                     });
             }
              })
            });
      </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Use your eyes? If you do a console.log(json) instead you can inspect the results visually in the console.

Comment: I apologize I am relatively new to coding and jQuery / Javascript in particular. I will do that.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet I have used the console and I can now see the JSON format. Thank you for your help. I have another quick question if you have time. Can I call the 
$.getJSON('lou.json'), function(data) or would I need to phrase it differently? I'm not sure what I would call since this data has been converted to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a schema for the xml doc you're working with you could validate the output against the schema.

Comment: I have been looking through Firebug and Chrome Dev tools and can't see the JSON output.

Comment: @JonathanBritt, you should use `console.log` instead of `alert`, this way you'll see your JSON in your Chrome/Firefox console.

Comment: @BearProgrammer  Thanks for the help. I have done that and now I can see the data. I asked an earlier responder how I would go about calling this data now? I know you can call 
$.getJSON('lou.json'), function(data) { but I am not sure what "file" I would call since this has been converted from XML and is not stored locally. Any advice would be wonderful.

Comment: @JonathanBritt I think that you have no JSON file. What you get is a Javascript object which is the variable you called `json`. To access it's attributes, just use the `.` operator like you did to get the `message`. Here is a better example: http://jsfiddle.net/eCRVk/1/

Comment: @BearProgrammer Thank you for all your assistance. I am working on using console.log to get a feel for maneuvering through the JSON. If you had time later I would love to text chat on Skype for a few minutes to pick your brain on how I might tackle a project I am working on for school. However, I understand if you are reluctant. Thanks for all your help. My Skype name is britt.jonathan89

Answer (score 1):

Take the JSON output, use another utility to convert it back into XML, then run a diff to see if it is identical to the original XML.